# Обобщенные контейнеры без указателя на void

Tags: c, stl, containers

Я тут задумался над следующей проблемой.

Сейчас я работаю над библиотекой обобщенных контейнеров и алгоритмов, делаю это на **C** потому, что там, где будет использоваться эта библиотека, плюсы использовать физически невозможно. Использование **GLib** так же нежелательно.

Практически вся библиотека уже написана, и у меня появилось время подумать над некоторыми тонкостями реализации.

Я хорошо знаю **C++** и **STL**, поэтому при реализации контейнеров и алгоритмов часто ориентируюсь на производительность **STL** как на эталон, чтобы *сишный* вариант контейнера был не медленнее и не прожорливее.

Но в некоторых случаях этого добиться непросто.

Например, судя по тестам, **std::vector** содержит указатель на сплошной блок памяти, в котором хранятся сами объекты, а не указатели на них. Это без проблем реализуется и на **C**. И работает даже немного быстрее, чем *плюсовой* вариант.

Но можно ли реализовать на **C** обобщенные связные списки, хэш-таблицы и деревья без использования *лишнего* указателя на **void**?

Например, чтобы узел связного списка содержал не три указателя - **prev**, **next**, **data**, - а два указателя и блок данных заданного размера и выравнивания?

В ряде случаев это снизило бы потребление памяти (но это неточно), а так же в большинстве случаев увеличилась бы скорость доступа к данным (это тоже неточно)...

Но реализовывать это в **C**, по всей видимости, нужно с использованием черной макросной магии, которая учитывает размер указателя, требуемое для данных узла выравнивание и прочие тонкости.

Я поковырял **GLib**, и там практически везде используется простой вариант обобщенного узла, например, связного списка:

```
struct s_node
{
    struct s_node *prev, *next;
    void *data;
};
```

Это же относится к узлам деревьев и хэш-таблиц.

Почему это так? Только ли причина в том, что хранение в узле связного списка самих данных N-байтного размера с нужным выравниванием требует нехороших костылей? Или это связано с чем-то еще?

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Скорее всего причина в том, что в С++ за счет шаблонов можно создать целое семейство однотипных классов с разными фактическим размерами структуры, а на Си это не так легко сделать. Плюс от указателя на данные в структуре например в том, что можно легко обменять местами данные, не "переподвязывая" узлы. Ну и использовать один и тот же блок данных в разных узлах (правда, при этом нужно помнить, что если попытаться изменить содержимое блока данных, то он может поменяться в нескольких местах).

Comment: Возьмем в учет кэш процессора. Узел с указателем на данные занимает меньше места (если данные больше размера указателя), следовательно, в кэш влезет гораздо больше узлов, можно их быстрее перебирать (если не обращаться к самим данным). В общем, грамотное использование кэша во многих случаях решает.

Comment: Не факт, что узлов в кэш влезет больше, они почти наверняка не лежат в памяти один за другим. А если список заполняется и меняется по воле случая, тогда узлы с вероятностью 99.9% будут валяться далеко друг от друга.

Comment: Всё очень просто просто делается с помощью **C** шаблонов. Я отказался от плюсовых, так как там невозможно регулировать **inline** вариант. Обязаловка всё выгружать в хедеры меня добила. Так-как компиляция всего из-за одной строчки это просто издевательство. Создавайте свой шаблон `#define DEFCLASSDLIST(NAME) struct DList##NAME ...` и вперёд и с песней. Скорее всего в библиотеке не хотели использовать макросы. А с любым типом нужно работать индивидуально, по-этому : хотите своё, флаг вам в руки!

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Один вариант (с эмуляцией templates макросами) вам уже подсказали. [Другой](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h) (широко используемый в Linux) основан на включении полей связи контейнера (списка, RB-tree и т.п.) внутрь пользовательских структур данных, которые помещаются в контейнер. Не знаю, очевидный или не очень, плюс такого подхода заключается в том, что структура данных может одновременно находится в нескольких контейнерах (не обязательно одинаковых). Впрочем, необходимость этого сильно зависит от прикладной задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, в чем загвоздка. Берите и делайте блок с двумя указателями и местом для пользовательских данных. Как вариант, `node_header` может быть встроенным в пользовательские данные на его стороне, тогда это будет *интрузивный* список.

```
struct node;
typedef struct node node_t;

struct node_header;
typedef struct node_header node_header_t;

struct node_header
{
    node_t * p_prev;
    node_t * p_next;
};

node_t * make_node(size_t const data_size)
{
    char * const p_block = calloc(1, sizeof(node_header_t) + data_size);
    return (node_t *) p_block;
}

node_t * get_next(node_t * const p_node)
{
    node_t * p_next = NULL;
    if(p_node)
    {
        p_next = ((node_header_t *) p_node)->p_next;
    }
    return p_next;
}

void * get_data(node_t * const p_node)
{
    void * p_data = NULL;
    if(p_node)
    {
         p_data = (void *)(((char *) p_node) + sizeof(node_header_t));
    }
    return p_data;
}
```